# What is the name of dynamic, non-resistant form of sparring in Japanese?

Tags: training, judo, terminology

I think most of the Judoka know the ladder of Tandoku renshu, Uchi komi, Yakusoku geiko, Randori and Shiai as well as Kata as classical training forms.

But in Ne waza, there was another name introduced to me: Kakari geiko.

It was supposed to mean a form of Ne waza randori where you actually never want to stand still, but keep in fluent movement with one another, always searching for opportunities and the most efficient direction to apply momentum. No strong resistance, just playful, dynamic movement in Ne-waza. Ends up mostly in holds, sometimes armbars, but strangles interrupt the movement and I ended up to apply them rather other forms of Randori/Shiai.

After some research, I found that the Japanese nomenclature does not seem to fit this. In some sense, the "[continuous attack practice](http://www.judo-ch.jp/english/dictionary/terms/kakarigeiko/)" seems fitting, but it is both partners alternating instead of one and the same, and you do not get 'fresh' partners all the time.

Therefore I would like to ask whether there is a special name for that form of training (good for warming up and training the sense for direction of movement), or it simply is light randori.

**Disclaimer:** I am well aware that for many people, the Randori/Shiai divide is not really existing, which is kind of sad. It is there and important. I have the feeling that the coach chose a different name for the form of training in order not to let people hear "randori" and go all out. Therefore the question.

Comment: Randori (乱取り) translates as free style practice. Shihai (試合) translates as match or bout. Both are related but utterly different. Amalgamating both shows a lack of understanding of free play. BTW, kyousou (競争?) is competition, again something different.

Comment: @Sardathrion According to [a considerably long post here](http://www.e-budo.com/archive/index.php/t-53613.html) kyousou is competition in the sense of strive for the upper hand in a wide sense, whereas contest in martial arts context would rather be *shiai*. Tomiki used kyousou, though, possibly because it was rather conceptualised as a form of randori (fitting the whole aiki principle) and Ueshiba condemned *shiai*, as mentioned in an earlier post there.

Comment: Okay, we are reaching the limits of my limited Japanese here. [I asked  a question about this…](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/43511/6910)

Answer (score 2):

In  budo taijutsu we call it randori as well. Were the Uke attacks at faster than normal training speeds. The speed, assuming the Uke is trained well enough, is set by the Tori based on comfort levels.

Informally we have "flow drills" which equate to the different katas like Fu no kata or sui no kata

Answer (score 1):

In Shodokan Aikido, we call this *toshu randori* (empty hand free play?) and it works in pretty much the same way as you describe it for Judo. Mostly, one player initiates an attack, the second counters, the first counters, and so on until one of the players cannot counters. There is no tori or uke, both switch role as needed. It is definitely below even soft-randori in resistance but is a fantastic training tool.

Another good side effect of the exercise is that you can do it very slowly allowing less experience players to think their way through technique. This boost their confidence and allows them to start remembering patterns and combinations that work for them.

I strongly suspect that the exercise was ported by Tomiki to Aikido from Judo but I am not sure if the name has changed.

While there is no tanto involved, this used to be the stage before randori in Tomiki's early system which did not involve a tanto. However, everyone quickly close the distance and started using Judo. So, Tomiki introduced the tanto to create more distance and to give uke some way to score points instead of being passive. The latter forces uke to attack strongly.

Comment: In my understanding it is *toshu* as different from *tanto*, i.e. free-handed attacks (and counters) versus knife-attacks. Therefore, it comes down to simply randori again, isn't it?

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking Answer edited.